# 1 dimensional CW complex, every loop homotopic to finite sequence of edges traversed monotonically

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having some problems with the following exercise from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (1.1.19 at page 39):

Show that if $X$ is a path-connected $1$-dimensional CW complex with basepoint $x_0$ a $0$-cell, then every loop in $X$ is homotopic to a loop consisting of a finite sequence of edges traversed monotonically.

First of all I'm not sure what "monotonically" means in this context. Does it mean that you don't go back to a edge or what?

My other problem (besides actually doing the proof) is this: Say X has one 0-cell and an infinite amount of 1-cells, all connected to the 0-cell in both ends. Then how can you find a loop traversing a finite number of edges that is homotopic to the loop traversing all the edges in this $X$ once?

Comment: My idea would be to use compactness to show every loop traverses only finitely many edges and then argue by induction on the number of edges.

Comment: Monotonically in this setting means that it is piecewise injective. You can partition the interval $[0,1]$ into subintervals $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ such that $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots <t_n=1$ and the path $\gamma \colon [t_i,t_{i+1}] \to X$ is injective for all $i$. Edit: also $\gamma([t_i,t_{i+1}])$ should be an entire edge for every $i$, not a piece of an edge or a collection of more than one edge.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thank you, will try it.

Comment: @DanRust I see. And the loop i talked about in the last paragraph is not possible to construct. I will try to do the proof. Many thanks.

Comment: If you manage to work it out, you should post your solution so that the question does not remain unanswered. I'll try to remember to upvote, if it's correct.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Sorry for the late reply, but I got stuck and tried to give it a break. In my proof I need to show that there exists a partition $0=s_0<\cdots <s_n=1$ such that every closed interval $[s_i,s_{i+1}]$ is mapped to the closure of a 1-cell. Any input on how to do that?

Comment: Let $\{x_\alpha\}$ be the set of vertices on the loop. It suffices to show this is finite. Fix $\alpha$. Denote by $\{E_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ the set of 1-cells whose closure contains $x_\alpha$. If the closure of $E_i$ contains another vertex, remove it and call the resulting subspace $J_i$. Let $U_\alpha$ be the union of the $J_i$. This is an open neighborhood of $x_\alpha$. Now, by construction the $U_\alpha$ form an open cover for the loop, hence compactness yields the conclusion.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thank you very much. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first show that there exists a partition $0=s_0<\cdots<s_m=1$ such that every closed interval $[s_i,s_{i+1}]$ is mapped to the closure of a 1-cell.

Let $\{x_\alpha\}$ be the set of vertices on the loop. It suffices to show that this is finite. Fix $\alpha$. Denote by $\{E_i\}_{i\in I}$ the set of 1-cells whose closure contains $x_\alpha$. If the closure of $E_i$ contains another vertex, remove it and call the resulting subspace $J_i$. Let $U_\alpha$ be the union of the $J_i$. This is an open neighborhood of $x_\alpha$. Now by construction the $U_\alpha$ form an open cover for the loop, hence compactness yields the conclusion.

Now let $\gamma$ be our loop, and let $\gamma_i:[s_i,s_{i+1}]\to\overline{E_\beta}$, where $\overline{E_\beta}$ is the closure of a 1-cell, be the restriction of the loop to $[s_i,s_{i+1}]$. There are two cases:

1) $\gamma_i(s_i)=\gamma_i(s_{i+1})$. If $\overline{E_\beta}$ has two different vertices, $\gamma_i$ is contractible since $\overline{E_\beta}$ is simply connected. If it has one, it is homeomorphic to $S^1$, so $\gamma_i$ is homotopic to a path traversing $\overline{E_\beta}$ monotonically a finite number of times.

2) $\gamma_i(s_i)\neq\gamma_i(s_{i+1})$. Let $f:[s_i,s_{i+1}]\to\overline{E_\beta}$ be a monotone path from $\gamma_i(s_i)$ to $\gamma_i(s_{i+1})$. Then $\gamma_i\cdot \overline{f}$ is a loop at $\gamma_i(s_i)$ and contractible since $\overline{E_\beta}$ is simply connected. It follows that $\gamma_i$ is path homotopic to $f$.

By combining all the homotopies for segments of $I$, we get a homotopy between $\gamma$ and a loop consisting of a finite sequence of edges traversed monotonically.

Comment: It is not true that $\overline{E_\beta}$ is simply connected. This is true if it has two distinct vertices, but if it has only one, it is homeomorphic to $S^1$, so you need to take this into account. This shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @VincentBoelens That's right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This answer is not correct. It's easy to show there are only finitely many vertices in the image, but that does not imply there is a partition. In Example 1.25 Hatcher, the shrinking wedge of circles has only one vertex with infinitely many "edges". As in the example there is a loop without such a partition. You have to use the fact that $X$ is a CW complex to get the partition.